# Adminpanel hangs for a couple of seconds

Tags: admin-panel

When I try to access the admin panel and after I login at every click, the site just hangs for a few seconds, usually between 12-30 seconds.

Store works fine, without any issues.

What I have done:

- Checked older versions of site and db, they do the same, although as far as I can remember those saves used to work okay.
- I check for sleep(#) in code
- performed maintenance on site (Cleared cache, logs, etc.)
- upgraded site/modules to newest possible version.

Any Pointers?

Comment: Can you provide more info please, which version are you on? Are all your caches enabled? If it's Magento 2 are you in client-side or server-side compilation?

Comment: I have version 1.8 1.8.2 and 1.9.2 of the same site. They all have the same symptom

Answer (score 0):

did you clear/empty the /var/cache folder on the server and then clear your own web browser cache? you may want to also clear your var/sessions folder.
remember backup first. :)

~B.

Comment: Yes, also moved site to other server with other hosting settings.

Comment: do you have Tools> Compilation> disabled or enabled?

Comment: I have tried it both with on and off.

Comment: have you re indexed?

Comment: of course. Please note that I have mentioned that the store itself is working nicely. Only the admin panel is messing up.